# Rcov show files wih 0% code coverage not considered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rcov

I'm currently running rcov in a Rails Project (ruby 1.8.7). I let Jenkins take care of the overview of the code coverage.

Unfortunately only files that have a code coverage greater than 0.0% are shown.

This leads to a wrong total coverage.

Is there a way to include all files that have not been touched in the test run?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the threshold to 101, so it'll include the files with 100%.

It depends on your installation where you should put this. Here is the [documentation](http://rspec.info/documentation/tools/rcov.html) for RSpec 1.x for example.

Comment: The threshold is to 101 by default. The files with 100% coverage are already shown, I'm missing the files with 0.0% coverage

Comment: oh, read it wrong. In that case: you need to require *all* the files to make sure they end up in the report.